# XSLT 1.0 Display unique values from 2 nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

does anyone know how to use a key to only select distinct values from 2 different nodes?

If I had the following XML BLock let's say..

```
<value>
  <books>
    <book>Book 1</book>
    <title>Title 1</title>
    <genre>Action</genre>
  </books>
  <books>
    <book>Book 2</book>
    <title>Title 1</title>
    <genre>Action</genre>
  </books>
</value>
```

And I wanted to show books that had distinct genre and title.  Not separately, but combined.  So if I had 10 items and all 10 of them had BOTH the same genre and title, it would only show 1 book.

I know I have to have a key and reference it in a for-each, but I can't get it to use multiple keys.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try one of the many, many answers here on SO that show how [Muenchian grouping](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22muenchian%20grouping%22) works.

Comment: In particular, look at solutions that discuss composite keys - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706412/grouping-by-2-fields-in-xsl, for instance.

Comment: If you are still having trouble with this, would it be possible for you to post the XSLT you are currently using, along with your expected output. Thanks!